# PHP one to many MySQL relationship

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, im trying to display table showing number of single order next to name of somebody. To understand, my database looks like:

```
---monterzy---
-id
-name
-surname
--------------

---zlecenia---
-id
-nr_zlecenia  (number i want to display)
-monterzy_id
--------------
```

I want to make it display zlecenia.nr_zlecenia next to correct name and surname from monterzy (monterzy_id the same as monterzy.id)
and my php code looks like:

```
      $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }

  $sql = "SELECT zlecenia.nr_zlecenia, monterzy.name, monterzy.surname FROM zlecenia JOIN monterzy ON zlecenia.monterzy_id = monterzy.id";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  include("scripts/header.php");
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
      echo "<center><b>Zlecenia:</b><br><br><table><tr><th>nr zlecenia</th><th>Imie</th><th>Nazwisko</th><th style='width:32px'>Usuń</th></tr>";
      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<tr><td style='width:5%' align='center'> " . $row["zlecenia.nr_zlecenia"]. "</td><td> " . $row["monterzy.imie"]. "</td><td> " . $row["monterzy.nazwisko"]. "</td><td style='width:32px'><a href=\"delete-monter.php?id=$row[id]\"><img src='img/error.png'></a></td></tr>";
      }
      echo "</table></center>";
  } else {
      echo "<center><b>Brak wyników</b></center>";
  }

  $conn->close();
```

I dont know what am i doing wrong, but the table is empty. It's not connection problem, it workes flawlesly with simple query. Thanks for adwise!

Comment: Do a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Are the id's of zlecenia.monterzy_id defined as foreign key to monterzy.id and are there any values that mach? Did you run the query in MySQL and got a result?

Comment: Show some sample data

Comment: The id's do not have to be foreign keys @MaD, but there do have to be matching values.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard. Correct.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ I know @MaD!

Comment: Changing JOIN to LEFT JOIN did nothing, as example data i have monterzy: 35,John,Test and in zlecenia: 1,111,35

Comment: I tried in phpMyAdmin and the query works flawlessly, idk what to do

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem, i had to change echo in loop to

```
echo "<tr><td style='width:5%' align='center'> " . $row["nr_zlecenia"]. "</td><td> " . $row["imie"]. "</td><td> " . $row["nazwisko"]. "</td><td style='width:32px'><a href=\"delete-monter.php?id=$row[id]\"><img src='img/error.png'></a></td></tr>";
```

You cant use variables like monterzy.imie but simple imie. It may make a problem when dealing with the same names in diffrent tables, but now it works perfect. Thanks!